# Is there any free dataset available for https://docs.oracle.com/en/?

Tags: java

I need to have https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html data as a csv file.
Or is there any API I can extract these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all modules from Java 9 with the following command:

```sh
java --list-modules
```

Otherwise you can use the [ModuleLayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html) to get the foundational API:

```java
ModuleLayer.boot().modules().stream().map(Module::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**EDIT**:

If you need the description from the website, you can use the html parser [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). There is also a nice [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-with-jsoup).

```java
String url = "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/overview-summary.html";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element table = document.select("table").first();
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to also get the comments(descriptions) for them?

Comment: I guess it is not possible because the description is not saved anywhere. You can get some details with `java --describe-module java.sql` for each module or `ModuleLayer.boot().modules().stream().map(Module::getDescriptor).forEach(System.out::println);`. Otherwise if you need the description, you can use the html parser [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). There is also a nice [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-with-jsoup).